# How to refresh data from plist in Table View?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

so I have this situation. I have a table view, with custom cells from NIB. I'm taking data from plist into the properties of each cell. Problem is, when I change a view, from that view I'm changing the array from what the data should be from, getting back to the table view, and the data won't refresh, and the app gonna crash. 
Thanks for every advice!!!

My .m file looks like this:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *citiesButton;

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *path;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dict;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *city;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *rowData;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    rowValue = @"Brno";

    self.path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Database2" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:_path]; //Main Dictionary
    self.city = [_dict objectForKey:rowValue];

    [self.citiesButton setTitle:rowValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
{
    tableView.rowHeight = 100;
    UINib *nib  = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MIKETableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = tableView.contentInset;
    contentInset.top = 20;
    [tableView setContentInset:contentInset];

    NSLog(@"rowValue is %@", rowValue);
    self.city = [_dict objectForKey:rowValue];
}

    NSLog(@"Main view loaded successfuly");
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.citiesButton setTitle:rowValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"View will appear");



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.city count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //this is space
    return 50;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    self.rowData = _city[indexPath.section];
    NSLog(@"All keys for dict: %@", [self.dict allKeys]);

    cell.timeLabel.text = _rowData[@"Time"];
    cell.priceLabel.text = _rowData[@"Price"];
    cell.infoLabel.text = _rowData[@"Info"];


    cell.infoLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "when I change a view"? Do you show some view in your TableViewController or you create another view controller to display that view? If latter, then how do you create it, does the TableViewController gets dismissed (destroyed)?

Comment: I'm guessing you go to  detail view and then back. Have you tried [reload tableview];

Comment: hey ,when you navigate from one view controller to another and get back to first view controller you should update the stuff in viewWillAppera and check for the array elements.

Comment: Well the original view controller is not dissmissed... I tried to create the table view in ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad and it did not helped...